# Using Watir and IE 7 to download files

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir

Based off of this discussion: [Watir Web driver to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834130/watir-web-driver-to-download-file)

Is there any other way similar to this to download a file using Watir without using something like RAutomation or AutoIT?  The website I have to use is only formatted for IE and breaks when using other browsers.

Comment: You have to use a browser-based solution?  You can't use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) and/or [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to go that route.  I tried to at first but didn't know how to send the authentication correctly to get the response.    This was a quick solution that I was trying out.  I did end up getting it to work with Watir and RAutomation.  If you have any online resources that can help me with syntax, that would be a more robust solution.  Thanks!